# Change checkbox design for Symfony Form (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, symfony-forms, symfony

Currently I use Symfony 3.0 with the default Bootstrap 3 form template.
`bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig`

I like to extend the form template to have all my checkboxes like this:

```
<div class="md-checkbox-list">
    <div class="md-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="md-check">
        <label for="checkbox1">
            <span></span>
            <span class="check"></span>
            <span class="box"></span> Option 1 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="md-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="md-check" checked>
        <label for="checkbox2">
            <span></span>
            <span class="check"></span>
            <span class="box"></span> Option 2 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="md-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="md-check">
        <label for="checkbox3">
            <span></span>
            <span class="check"></span>
            <span class="box"></span> Option 3 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="md-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" disabled class="md-check">
        <label for="checkbox4">
            <span></span>
            <span class="check"></span>
            <span class="box"></span> Disabled </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I do this? I tried a lot of things but I don't get it working. The Symfony Form templates are really complicated. Changes of some inputs or other easy things are working fine but checkboxes are not easy.

I hope somebody could help me because I have a lot of designs like these where I don't understand how to modify the checkbox style to look like this.

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes are rendered by the [checkbox_widget block](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig#L117-L126). You need to [create your own form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) that overrides this block with your own layout.

When you are dealing with lists of checkboxes, you will also have to customise the [choice_widget_expanded block](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig#L95-L115). You need to be careful here as the type being used inside the choice depends on wether or not multiple selections are possible (radio vs. checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a FormType to define your form.

```
$builder->add('cb1',  CheckboxType::class)->add('cb2',  CheckboxType::class);
```

Then in your twig, something like

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-horizontal form-bordered'} }) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.cb1, 'cb1 label', { 'attr': {'class': 'control-label'} }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.cb1, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control custom-cb-class'} }) }}
    </div>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```